# identify the row in my time vector where the time is 5 seconds before the last printed time, times are however in milliseconds

Tags: matlab

My matrix has a coloumn with times in it - times are in milliseconds (milliseconds since midnight - but dont worry about that).

I need to identify the row where the time is 5 seconds less than the last time in the matrix 
this is because i am going to loop through the matrix and look at data 5 seconds ahead so I need to know where to end my
for i = 1:rows in matrix minus wherever we hit the last 5 seconds so if looking 5 seconds forward we dont exceed the matrix dimensions.

So lets pretend the time is in coloumn 2 of the matrix 
and we have 
[rows,coloums] = size(matrix)

the last time stamp in the matrix  is (rows,2) and returns  time in milliseconds since midnight as for example  53997401 so 5 seconds before or my marker is therefor (53997401-5000)

therefor I am looking to find the last time in coloumn2 which is before the above number or 
search look down matrix(:,2) and return the row where (xxx,2) is less than (matrix(rows,2)-5000)

even if it returns a new vector  of all rows where coloum2 is less than   (matrix(rows,2)-5000) then we can just get the size of that vecor to see what the last row is which meets our criteria

in plain english  look down here and return the row where ans < for example 53997364 ie the return would be 4

```
53984704
53991775
53992283
53992283
53997367
53997367
53997367
53997367
53997401
53997401
```

Answer (score 3):

For your sample vector (let's call it `t`):

```
find(t < t(end) - 5000, 1, 'last')
ans = 4
```

For the full matrix, it's almost the same thing:

```
find(matrix(:,2) < matrix(end,2) - 5000, 1, 'last')
```

Comment: thanks very much thats a lot simpler than my multi step method - if you see this could you clarify the ,1, and I was not aware you could use 'last' is it just in the find function?

Comment: Type `doc find` at the MATLAB prompt to read the documentation for the `find` function.  One of the calling signatures is `ind = find(X, k, 'last')`, which "returns at most the last k indices corresponding to the nonzero entries of X".  So we're looking for the last 1 index where the inequality is true.